# JS error Vb.net embedded browser

Tags: vb.net

I have a program with an embedded browser. When I try to load a site, (Motdgd.com) it throws the error

> the value of the property 'atob' is null or undefined not a function object

Line 101
Char 5

I have searched extensively, but cannot find an answer.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim AdLink As String

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Count = 1
        UserLink = TextBox1.Text
        Label1.Text = UserLink
        WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(UserLink)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What have you tried.....Can you show your code? Hard to troubleshoot and help you without seeing what you've done so far.

Comment: Edited with code, have not tried much, as I am unable to determine the meaning of the error

Comment: Sorry, fixed that, was an error in copying it over, was not the problem

Comment: atob is not supported by IE 7/8/9 (and 10 in 7/8/9 mode). That is the problem and you wouldn't have it with chrome or Firefox. I have a feeling your trying to scrape some data...

Comment: So I need to embed Chromium of Mozilla into my program? Why is it not using IE10?

Comment: Yes Firefox, Chrome or IE10 but can't be 7,8 or 9 mode...

Comment: Is there a way to force IE10?

Comment: atob method decodes a string of data which was encoded by btoa...

Comment: You can change compatibility mode but won't work ...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
            InitializeComponent();
        RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", 11999, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        Key.Close();
```

Will force IE11 to run, via the registry